# iterate over a dict of dataframes to get a subset of the dataframes with selectd columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have multiple dataframes (exemple bellow contains only three) and I need create a function that selects only the columns I want to keep in then.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "column1": np.random.randint(100, 1000, 100),
        "column2": np.random.randint(200, 2000, 100),
        "column3": np.random.randint(300, 3000, 100),
        "column4": np.random.randint(400, 4000, 100),
        "column5": np.random.randint(500, 5000, 100),
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "column1": np.random.randint(80, 800, 100),
        "column2": np.random.randint(50, 500, 100),
        "column3": np.random.randint(30, 300, 100),
        "column4": np.random.randint(10, 100, 100),
        "column5": np.random.randint(500, 5000, 100),
    }
)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "column1": np.random.randint(2, 20, 100),
        "column2": np.random.randint(80, 300, 100),
        "column3": np.random.randint(30, 500, 100),
        "column4": np.random.randint(60, 700, 100),
        "column5": np.random.randint(900, 3000, 100),
    }
)
```

For this, I -must- use a dict in the form:

```
dict_of_dfs = {"df1": df1, "df2": df2, "df3": df3}
```

and I -must- create a function that select the columns I need to keep:

```
features = ["column3", "column4", "column5"]
```

It can't be the ones I need to drop, but the ones to keep (not df = df.drop(columns='x', 'y', 'z')
but df = df[features]).

I tried something like this:

```
def select_columns(dict_of_dfs, features):
    for df in dict_of_dfs:
        df = df[features]
```

and then:

```
select_columns(dict_of_dfs, features)
```

but I always get the error 'string indices must be integers'

Could anyone explain me why it happens? I'm pretty sure it's about mutable and immutable, but I'm noob at python and the reason that my logic doesn't work doesn't make sense for me..

Comment: please accept one of the answers as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So, when you iterate over `dict_of_dfs` it returns keys rather than values (which are `"df1"`, `"df2"`, ...), hence the error you are getting.
In `select_columns` you need to correct change the code inside the loop to modify the values (which are the dataframes) rather than the keys (the strings), this should make it work:

```
def select_columns(dict_of_dfs, features):
    for df in dict_of_dfs:
        dict_of_dfs[df] = dict_of_dfs[df][features]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a dict of dfs and function, you could iterate through the dfs and drop unnecessary columns with `drop` and `inplace=True`. Doing it this way, you must use `inplace=True` though, which is not available with `loc` -- otherwise you could select columns you want to keep instead of dropping ones you don't need:

```
features = ['column3', 'column4', 'column5']
dfs = (df1,df2,df3)

for df in dfs:
    df.drop([col for col in df.columns if col not in features], axis=1, inplace=True)
```